# jQuery - Stop ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

(I really didn't know how to title this, feel free to suggest an edit)

Consider the following sample html:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item"><span class="icon"></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span class="icon"></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span class="icon"></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span class="icon"></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span class="icon"></span></div>
</div>
```

Attached to each `.icon` is some jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.icon').click(function(){
        runAjaxStuff();
        displayNewContent();
    })
</script>
```

In a nutshell, each time a user clicks an `.icon`, the corresponding parent `.item` will perform an AJAX request and finish by displaying additional `.item` content on the page.

If a user, in this scenario, were to click each of the `.item` quickly in succession, the AJAX request from a preceeding click is likely to still be waiting for a response. Of course, the new content is also not displayed yet; however, after a handful of seconds and all the requests have had a chance to complete, the user is then barraged with tons of new content being displayed all at once.

What I am after is a method to simply stop execution of any previous `click` bindings if an `.icon` is clicked so that only the most recent click ultimately completes.

I am aware that I can make my AJAX call syncronous instead, but I am hoping for a better way that will not seize the user's browser. My jQuery is good enough to get by, but this is something a little more in-depth than I'm used to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got two choices

You can cancel the previous Ajax calls that are open

```
var xhr = null;
jQuery('.icon').click(function () {
    if (xhr &&  && xhr.readystate != 4) {
        xhr.abort();
    }
    runAjaxStuff();
    displayNewContent();
});
```

and in your ajax call you would store the call to the

```
xhr = $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/progress.ftl',
    success: function(data) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

or

You can set a "active" flag and not make calls until the last one is complete

```
var isActive = false;
jQuery('.icon').click(function () {
    if (isActive) {
        return;
    }
    isActive = true;
    runAjaxStuff();
    displayNewContent();
});
```

and in the success/error/done function

```
isActive = false;
```

And you probably want to give the user some notification that either the call is active or that the last call was cancelled just so they know what is happening. Give them a good UX so they do not randomly click.

Comment: +1 Because prevention is always the best way. But if the OP prefers to abort the previous AJAX call - as he specified to perform the most recent click - he may want to check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/446626/2600397

Comment: I'd definitely prefer stop/abort, simply because instead of restricting the user, it lets the user do what he wants and deals with it.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is not simply AJAX to stop, but possibly animation as well (inside `displayNewContent`). Will each need to be explicitly stopped individually?

Comment: Well depending of what you want to accomplish, you should stop everything that's moving. I strongly suggest you to go for the "prevention" way.

Comment: You can add a common class and call `stop()` or do it the first way and not make a request until everything is done. Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to unbind `click`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.icon').click(function(){
        $('.icon').unbind('click');  // unbind click
        runAjaxStuff();
        displayNewContent();
    })
</script>
```

Then bind it again in `complete` event that has `$.ajax` method:

```
complete: function() {
    $('.icon').bind('click'); // will fire either on success or error
}
```